# Select Where Json Array Mysql 5.7

Tags: json, mysql-5.7

I have this json stored:

```
[{"id": "1", "nome": "11"}, {"id": "2", "nome": "12"}, {"id": "3", "nome": "13"}]
```

I'm trying to search something like this:

```
SELECT * from acessos where ddd->>"$[*].nome" = '13';
```

And this is not working.

I thought the path was wrong, but if I try:

```
SELECT ddd->>"$[*].nome" from acessos
```

I get this result:

```
["11", "12", "13"]
```

Someone knows how to search in JSON array this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
set @j = '[{"id": "1", "nome": "11"}, {"id": "2", "nome": "12"}, {"id": "3", "nome": "13"}]';
-- select JSON_SEARCH(@j,"All","13");
set @x = select substr(JSON_SEARCH(@j, "All", "13"),4,1);
select json_extract(@j,"$[@x]")
```